# Are the Fermat numbers a geometric Progression?

Tags: number-theory

I read that for a sequence to be a geometric progression multiplying any element in the sequence by some constant say, $a$ gives the next digit in the sequence.

I know that $$2^{2^n}+1=F_n$$

So there isn't a constant I could multiply it by to get the next term. Does that mean the Fermat numbers aren't a geometric progression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct the Fermat numbers do not form a geometric progression, for the reason you state.  "Element" would be a better term than "digit" and "sequence" better than "pattern" in the statement.

Comment: Well I got that test question wrong lol.